# Why would a background video work perfectly in Safari but not in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I am building a website in a specific builder for a client and I brought in a small background hero video, hosted on AWS s3. 
It works totally fine on Safari on Mac OS and iOS but for some reason it will not display on Google Chrome for desktop or mobile. 
I am including a link to show my process of building that way you all can see exactly what's going on:

https://share.vidyard.com/watch/x4Jc39b2HvFKdiGEp9WQMY?

Also here is a link to the actual site. https://app.getocta.com/v2/preview/4QDIYFuUHsn81JT2Pdmh

Comment: Please give us some debug information, or a link or some code, otherwise we can not help you very well.

Comment: Browsers are different and offer varying levels of support for languages.  Check F12 console for errors.  And debug in the browser where it's not working to see where the problem occurs.  We can't help with no info.

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please. [ask]

Comment: Thanks guys! I will go look for more info to better ask the question.

Comment: This is what I find when I go to the Console, also I have included the link to the actual page above... [Intervention] An <img> element was lazyloaded with loading=lazy, but had no dimensions specified. Specifying dimensions improves performance. See https://crbug.com/954323